# Generics on ASP.NET page Class

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, generics

I want to implement Generics in my Page Class like :

```
Public Class MyClass(Of TheClass)
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
```

But for this to work, I need to be able to instantiate the Class (with the correct Generic Class Type) and load the page, instead of a regular Response.Redirect. Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: I don't understand what role Response.Redirect has in instantiating a class or loading a page. Can you expound more on what you are trying to do?

Comment: Response.Redirect is one of the ways to load a Page. But I want to load my Page when its Class exhibits a Generic Behavior, like the eg. I submitted.

Comment: Can you give a more concrete example? What would you expect TheClass to be, and where would you expect it to come from?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure to fully understand what you want to do.
If you want something like a generic Page, you can use a generic BasePage and put your generic methods into that BasePage:

```
Partial Public Class MyPage
    Inherits MyGenericBasePage(Of MyType)

End Class

Public Class MyGenericBasePage(Of T As New)
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Public Function MyGenericMethod() As T
        Return New T()
    End Function

End Class

Public Class MyType

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer that says to derive a type from the generic type is a good one. However, if your solution involves grabbing a page based upon a type determined at runtime then you should be able to handle the PreRequestHandlerExecute event on the current HttpApplication.

This event is called just before a Request is forwarded to a Handler, so I believe you can inject your page into the HttpContext.Current.Handler property. Then you can create the page however you wish.